# Rails: subdomain constraints on identical controller names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

What's the correct way to have similarly named controllers in different namespaces if the constraint is a subdomain?

```
resources :documents
root to: 'documents#index'

constraints subdomain: 'test' do
  scope module: 'test' do
    resources :documents
    root to: 'documents#index' # this should hit the controller inside a module subfolder
  end
end
```

Should that not refer `http://localhost:3000/documents` to `DocumentsController` and `http://test.localhost:3000/documents` to `Test::DocumentsController`? What am I missing? Presently the latter just routes to the former. Both controllers exist in the right place, i.e., `DocumentsController` is in `/controllers` and the namespaced one is in `/controllers/test`?

Namespacing it returns it to the wrong controller too:

```
constraints subdomain: 'test' do
  namespace :test, path: nil do
    scope module: 'test' do
      resources :documents
      root to: 'documents#index'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a `resources :photos` above a `get 'photos/poll'` the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.

So, I believe in your example you should move your constrained routes above the non-constrained routes so they'll get a chance to match first, and then you'll "fallback" to the non-constrained documents resource if you aren't on the subdomain.

```
constraints subdomain: 'test' do
  scope module: 'test' do
    resources :documents
    root to: 'documents#index' # this should hit the controller inside a module subfolder
  end
end

resources :documents
root to: 'documents#index'
```

Should do it.

**Edit**

That was half the problem, the other half was [this](https://gist.github.com/indiesquidge/b836647f851179589765). It needs the `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0` line in the `development.rb` config.

Comment: That makes sense, I always forget the order of the routes, although it appears I'm still hitting the original controller and layout after making those changes. It just seems like `scope module: 'test'` is being ignored or something.